# C++ function member return

Tags: c++

I am currently learning the basics of C++ and I have found the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass {
    int x;
public:
    MyClass(int val) : x(val) {}
    int& get() {return x;}
};

int main() {
  MyClass foo (10);
  foo.get() = 15;  
  cout << foo.get() << '\n';

  return 0;  
}
```

I don't understand why the line `foo.get() = 15` works. To me it looks like a get and set at the same time. I guess it works due to the return type being `int&` and not only `int`.

Can someone explain to me how it works?

Thanks.

Comment: It's analogous to `int* get() { return &x; }` and `*foo.get() = 15;` Note that in this case, you may as well just make the x public.

Comment: It works because it returns a reference to member variable `x`. That is, an alias of member variable `x`.

Comment: But why it should not work? Yes, get and assign to it.

Comment: I really *hate* this pattern :(

Comment: @paulm You'd hate C# then.

Comment: Why? This isn't possible in C#, unless you mean properties which are not the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Your `foo.get` is returning a [*reference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29) to an `int` (noted `int&`).

References can be assigned (so they are *l-values*). Read the wikipage on [C++ references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C%2B%2B%29), it is explaining better than I have time to. Or read carefully a good C++ programming book, like e.g. Stroustrup's [Programming : Principles and Practice Using C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html) or [a Tour of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/Tour.html) or [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html) (or all of them!)

As [Neil Kirk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2068573/neil-kirk) commented, you could *nearly* see references as a pointer implicitly dereferenced. In other words, and if you are familiar with C, think of `int* get() { return &x; }` and `*foo.get() = 15;`

See also this [*reference vs. pointer* question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21884825/reference-vs-pointer)

Comment: seeing references as a pointer implicitly dereferenced is as wrong as it is untrue.

Comment: I agree that is not exactly true, but if you have a better way to explain it in a few sentences, please try.

Comment: 90% of the time a reference is just a *const pointer in disguise.

Comment: `int *p = NULL; int &r = *p;` (trolling, but informative trolling, as there is no magic non-null protection that people think there can be)

Comment: @NeilKirk: That dereferencing is Undefined Behavior, you lost before you came to initializing the reference.

Comment: Learn to accept criticism when you state something that is untrue and misleading. A reference is just an alias for a variable.

Comment: Depending on your definition of variable: `int&i = t[j];` might not fit (since the only C++ variables are `t`, `j` and the defined ref `i`)

Answer (score 2):

The line works because the function is returning a *reference*, that's semantically equivalent to:

```
  int* get() {return &x;}
```

and:

```
  *foo.get() = 15;
```

Comment: @Josh -1, what is your point exactly? Paul is talking about this specific use, not all uses of references ever.

Comment: @MattMcNabb thanks. of course the compiler enforces a different set of *rules* on *references* with respect to *pointers*, such as making it *very* difficult to reseat or zero a *reference*, but the topic is deep enough to be well outside the scope of both the OP's question and SO itself.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the return value from function is a variable which it is stored in the stack or the heap, but without a known name to you.
so here

```
int& get() {return x;}
```

so foo.get() as one group ( foo.get() ) return a variable, in your case this is a by reference variable which mean the return of (foo.get()) is the variable x inside the foo class.

so doing foo.get() = 15 is same as doing foo.x = 15 because its return by reference.

Note : foo.x = 15 will give compiler error because x is private by default, but its very okay to return it as reference to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Code written is perfectly valid. You return non-constant reference to user code. User assigns to it, so your class member variable gets new value.

It seems that you are worrying about preserving [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) here. From this perspective, in a form you written it, your getter is not correct. Most times we return either a value or a constant reference:

```
int get() { return x; }

const int& get() { return x; }
```

This way user will not be able to mutate member variable returned. Getter is a dumb "return me" function, so, most times, we assume that it shall not mutate internal class state. To be cautious, we also often make getters constant members:

```
const int& get() const { return x; }
```

Of course there are exceptions (notably, [lazy eveluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation)). And also, user could cast out constness. But it is another story.

See also: [Const-correctness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Const-correctness), [Mutator_method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method), [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) ("Best practices" and "Intermediate")